# Rendering Displaying Transparent Default Grid (Blender 2.8)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

See title. I've been trying to troubleshoot this issue for the past few hours or so, but I haven't found a solution. I have an active camera in my scene, and I am sure that it has been selected as the main camera. I've also gone through most forum/Stack posts about the issue, but most of them are for versions before 2.8.

The curious thing is that I was able to render some frames just fine earlier this afternoon, which are currently stored in the tmp file. Anything beyond that range of frames does not render. I've tried deleting the files in the tmp folder to force it to re-render, but that results in only blank, transparent frames. The only thing I could possibly think of is that after rendering the images, I saved the file and then restarted my computer, but I'm not sure how that would affect it.

Attached is a link to my .blend file, if you'd like to take a look at it. I'm sure as a newbie there's probably an easy fix, but I simply can't figure this out.

edit: this file should now be downloadable, apologies!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BxYeztSM6txtUzCecx7mrCIQgC_EAdxj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: could you set permissions to the link so that it is downloadable? or use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload .blend files

Comment: @AkaiShuichi Yes, my apologies! The link should be downloadable now. Let me know if you have any issues.